# laravel validate date parts construction

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate a date but it's not working, I'm trying to reconstruct a date from parts and in my sanitize function I'm adding the value to be validated in the request. The date that I'm passing in is an invalid date to try and throw an error but I'm not getting it to work in my request class. I'm inputting 2020-02-30 for a date which is invalid because no such date exists

```
    $this->request->add(['event_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->request->get('month') . '/' . $this->request->get('day') . '/' . $this->request->get('year')))]);

    $input = $this->all();

    $input['owner_firstname'] = filter_var($input['owner_firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    ....
    ....
    $this->merge($input);  


    $rules = [
        'owner_firstname'       => 'required|min:2|max:30',
        'owner_lastname'        => 'required|min:2|max:30',
        'owner_email'           => 'email',
        'owner_type'            => 'required',
        'partner_firstname'     => 'required|min:2|max:30',
        'partner_lastname'      => 'required|min:2|max:30',
        'partner_email '        => 'email',
        'partner_type'          => 'required',
        'month'                 => 'not_in:0',
        'day'                   => 'not_in:0',
        'year'                  => 'required|digits:4|integer|min:' . date('Y') . '|max:'. (date('Y', strtotime('+9 months'))),
        'event_date'            => 'date',
        'event_city'            => 'required|not_in:0',
        'event_country'         => 'required|not_in:0',
        'number_of_guests'      => 'required',
        'guests_message'        => 'required|min:30|max:5000',
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1) The validation is passing because of the way you are constructing the date string to send to the validator.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('02/30/2020'))  // This becomes "2020-03-01"
```

So since March 1, 2020 is a valid date, the validation passes. Instead, you could just construct the date string with dashes directly.

2) There are cases (like AJAX requests) when calling `$this->request->add()` does not add the param to the result you get when calling `$this->all()`. Try adding the param with `merge()` instead.

```
// This will set the date as '2020-02-30' and fail validation
$this->merge(['event_date' => $this->request->get('year') . '-' . $this->request->get('month') . '-' . $this->request->get('day')]);
```